# Proving divisibility of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let us take a two digit  number and add it to its reverse.We have to prove that it is divisible by 11.
Same way,if we subtract the larger number from the other,it is divisible by 9.How can we explain these?

Comment: Can you give one example please

Comment: I think by reciprocal the OP means swapping the digits. So for example, if the two digit number was 34, then its "reciprocal" would be 43.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: any two digit number $ab$ can be represented in base 10 as: $$ab=10a+b$$with $1\le a\le 9$ and $0\le b \le 9$. Example: $$43=10(4)+3$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ 10a\!+\!b \equiv a\!+\!b\pmod{9},\ $ but $\ 10a\!+\!b \equiv -a\!+\!b\pmod{11}.$